# estimate of variance-covariance matrix for linear models with correlated observations

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

For linear models
$$y_{n \times1}=X_{n \times p}\beta_{p \times 1}+\epsilon_{n \times 1}, \text{ where }\epsilon \sim N(0,V)$$
If in a real life problem we have data as $(y_1,x_1),(y_2,x_2),...,(y_n,x_n)$ where $x_i$'s are row vectors in $X$, and we want to fit the data using the linear model above. Then how could we get a estimate of $V$?

I know usually, we are interested in estimating $\beta$ and the covariance of $\beta$. But here I want to find out the distribution of $y$, say $y \sim N_n(X\beta, V)$, then what is $V$? Is there an estimate of it?

For me, the vector $y$ is just one observation from the multinormal distribution $y \sim N_n(X\beta, V)$. Like in the univariate normal case, if we have an observation $z$ from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, we can estimate $\mu$ as $\hat{\mu}=\bar{z}=z$, but we can not estimate $\sigma^2$ since we only have one observation. So does that mean we cannot estimate $V$ here?

Moreover, if we have a linear mixed effect model
$$y=X\beta+Z\alpha+\epsilon$$
where $\beta$ is the fixed effect and $\alpha$ is the random effects, and
$$\epsilon \sim N(0, V) \text{ and }\alpha \sim N(0, \Omega)$$
Then is there a way to estimate $V$ and $\Omega$? Then we could find the covariance matrix of $y$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both models, the variance components (i.e., all parameters in the specification of the variance-covariance matrices $V$ and $\Omega$) are typically estimated using either the Restricted Maximum Likelihood or Maximum Likelihood approaches. These two approaches are, for example, implemented in function `lmer()` in the [**lme4**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lme4) package, and functions `gls()` and `lme()` in the [**nlme**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nlme) package in R.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I use `lmer`, so they will return a correlation matrix for random effects, which is quite close to `cov2cor(Omega)`, i.e. I will see this as the estimate of $\Omega$. But how could I get $V$? And for the model only has fixed effect, like the first one, I will normally use `lm`, but I did not see the estimate of $V$ in the `summary(lm)`.

Comment: Or in other words, I do not have to estimate $\Omega$ and $V$ separately in the mixed effect case. I only want to find an estimate of the variance of the response variable $y$.

Comment: The **lme4** package works under the random effects paradigm and cannot directly estimate a model with correlated error terms. This is available in the `lme()` function from the **nlme** package. From a mixed model fitted by `lme()`, you can get the covariance matrix of the marginal model for $y$ using the `getVarCov()` function.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any ideas under the fixed effects model like the first model I gave? I use `lm`, but they only give the `residuals` for each observation, i.e. `residual=observation-fitted value`, and this is not what  I want.

Comment: For the first model you will need to use function `gls()` from the **nlme** package and suitably specify its `correlation` and `weights` arguments.

Comment: Hi, I saw the examples about `getVarCov()` here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/getVarCov.html, still, it returns the covariance matrix of the coefficients, not the observations.

Comment: Function `getVarCov()` gives you the covariance matrix of your outcome variable, function `vcov()` gives you the covariance matrix of the estimated coefficients $\hat\beta$.

Comment: getVarCov(obj, type = "marginal") gives the covariance matrix of response vector y.